# How to cross a river bend with two too-short boards

Tags: geometry, puzzle

> There is a river that is $4$ meters across and makes a $90^\circ$ turn. Is it possible to cross the river by bridging it with only two planks, each $3.9$ meters long?

So the shape of the river is like a thick letter 'L'.  The planks are $0.1$ meters too short to simply cross the river with one of them. Also I don't see how to use the other plank.

Comment: I hope you don't mind that I've edited your post to make the title more indicative of the question, and to clean up the language, in hopes that it'll be better received on this site.

Comment: @MikePierce Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.  The planks are GH and EI.  $BG=BH = \frac {3.9}{\sqrt 2}$
[image]

Comment: -How did you/What too did you use to, draw that figure? I have problem posting geometry questions here.

Comment: @LoveInvariants:  I used Geogebra to draw the figure then the snipping tool to take the screen shot.  I find it a very useful combination.

Answer (score 0):

When you put the planks over the bend, you create a triangle, the four metres across the river directly, then the four metres up the river. The length of planks needed therefore is $\sqrt{4^2+4^2}=4\sqrt2\approx 5.6m$

Since $3.9×2=7.8m$, you easily have enough plank to cross. One method would be to bolt the planks together so the amount of plank that is layered is at most 1.7m, or you could leave the first plank with 2.1m on land and 1.8m off land, then carry the other plank and lay it between the other shore and the plank, then walk the rest.

Comment: And you are asserting that when you are 1.8m off the land on the extreme of the 1st plank with a 3.9m plank on your shoulder you will not fall in the water ?

Comment: Thats unlikely given the 2.1m still on land (you could weight it for extra confirmation), and you can use the plank like tightrope walkers use bars for balance.